# change the body and the title of my content type by css

Tags: theming, 7

I'm using the zen theme
I would like to customize with css, the "content type" that I created. Set a different font for the title and body. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) and find the appropriate class or id.
2. Look for kick start inside the [zen theme](http://drupal.org/project/zen) and follow the instructions to crete a sub theme.
3. Adjust the CSS found with firebug to your needs.

After all this is basic drupal theming stuff. [Check this out](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) to get a bigger picture.